# Matlab Segmentation Violation and Memory Assertion Failure

Tags: matlab, memory, segmentation-fault, hdf5, sungridengine

I am running multiple Matlab jobs in parallel on an Sun Grid Engine that is using Matlab 2016b. On my personal macbook I am running Matlab 2016a. The script is doing some MRI image processing, where each job uses a different set of parameters so that I can do parameter optimization for my image processing routine.

About half of the jobs crash however, either due to **segmentation violations**, **malloc.c memory assertion failures** ('You may have modified memory not owned by you.') or errors from **HDF5-DIAG** followed by a segmentation violation.

Some observations

1. The errors do not always occur in the same jobs or in the same
   functions, but the crashes occur in several groups of jobs, where the jobs within one group crash within one minute of another.
2. I am not using dynamic arrays anymore but preallocate my
   arrays. If the arrays turn out to be too small I extend them with
   for example `cat(array, zeros(1, 2000))`.
3. The jobs use partly the
   same computations so they can share data. I do this by first
   checking wether the data is already generated by another job. If so
   try to load it using a while loop with a maximum number of attempts
   and pauses of 1 second (since it might fail when another job is
   still writing to the file, if it waits a bit and retries it might
   succeed). If the loading fails after the maximum number of attempts
   or if the data does not exist yet, then this job performs the
   required computations and tries to save the data. If the data was
   saved by another job in the meantime then this job does not save the
   data anymore.
4. I am not using any C/C++ or MEX files.
5. I have tested a subset of some of the jobs on my own laptop with Matlab 2016a and on a linux computer with Matlab 2016b, those worked fine. But again, the problem occurs only after a few hundred (of the total 500 iterations), and I didn't run the full simulation on my own computer but only around 20 iterations due to time constraints.

Comment: Did you get any further on this? I observe very similar issues when using the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox (I pasted [here an exemplary crash dump](https://pastebin.com/rDrdwFur)). The crash occurs sometimes. The larger the tasks, the more likely it occurs. The cluster I am using is running CentOS 7.4 and Matlab 9.1 (R2016b)

Comment: Hi @normanius, I ended up restructuring the code to prevent simultaneous file reading/writing by different threads (which I had before but thought I had taken care of with spin locks). It could be that this concurrency was the problem, but it's not certain since I did quite some refactoring and plenty other things changed too... Do you observe systematic fall out?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I figured out that requesting more memory when submitting the job on the batch system solves my problem. Matlab simply ran out of memory - therefore the failure in malloc. The Matlab functions I am using in average do not consume a lot of memory, but may show large peaks, depending on how well the training converges. Randomization of the input data leads to the sometimes behaviour that I observed.

Comment: But you may be right too. I also observed problems related to concurrent access to common resources, in particular when booting up Matlab. But I am not sure if this is related to the problems I had recently.